# How to extract branch name using regex and sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, unix-text-processing, text-capture

How can I extract the branch name from a string using bash? For example, I have the following command:

`branch=$(git branch -a --contains $sha)`

This may return:

1. `* branch-1.0` (the prefix is always an asterisk)
2. `branch-2.0 remotes/origin/branch-2.0` (here may be a new line instead of a space)
3. `master remotes/origin/master`
   (here may be a new line instead of a space)

And I need only the branch name (and only once) - `master`, `branch-2.0` or `branch-1.0`. I know it can be done with the `sed` command, but I can't figure out how.

I use the following regex: `(branch-[0-9].[0-9])|(master)`

Comment: _I use the following regex:_  : Write the full **sed** command, instead of just mentioning what you are using. Further, write what output you get from your sed-command for which input.

Comment: Simpy `git branch -a | cut -c2-` discards the first two columns.

Comment: You can do `git branch -a --format='%(refname:short)' --contains=$sha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done in Bash, without using an external regex parser:

```sh
# Read reference name path in an array splitting entries by /
IFS=/ read -ra refname < <(
  # Obtain full branch reference path that contains this sha
  git branch --format='%(refname)' --contains="$sha"
)

# Branch name is the last array element
branchname="${refname[-1]}"

printf 'The git branch name for sha: %s\nis: %s\n' "$sha" "$branchname"
```

Or using a POSIX-shell grammar only:

```sh
# Read reference path
refname=$(
  # Obtain full branch reference path that contains this sha
  git branch --format='%(refname)' --contains="$sha"
)

# Trim-out all leading path to get only the branch name
branchname="${refname##*/}"

printf 'The git branch name for sha: %s\nis: %s\n' "$sha" "$branchname"
```

**EDIT**:

As [Philippe mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70154301/how-to-extract-branch-name-using-regex-and-sed/70154900#comment124024332_70154301) `--format='%(refname:short)` will directly return the branch name without path, thus saving the need for further processing to extract it from the full reference path.

```sh
branchname=$(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --contains="$sha")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ branch=$(git branch -a --contains $sha | sed 's#.*/\|[^a-z]*##')
```

Using `awk`

```
$ branch=$(git branch -a --contains $sha | awk -F/ '{gsub("* ","");print $NF}')
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote yet) When I have enough reputation, I will vote for your answer. Thank you for your help!